# Normalize an array based on another array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array with size A = (n, L*w) and I have a maximum array with size MAX =(n, w). I want to normalize the

A based on the MAX array. I want to divide the value of array A to MAX by the window size of w. Here is
a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
A= np.random.randint(10, size = (2, 6))
MAX = np.random.randint(10, size = (2, 3))

A = np.array([[9, 1, 9, 4, 4, 9],
       [8, 9, 8, 1, 1, 2]])

MAX = array([[2, 7, 3],
             
       [7, 3, 3]])

out = [[4.5, 1/7, 3, 2, 4/7, 3],
       [8/7. 3, 8/3, 1/7, 1/3, 2/3]
```

The first indices (0-3) divided by the values of MAX and then again (3-6) divided by MAX. I tried to use this
code, however it does not work for my case:

```
def normalize(array, MAX):

    return array/MAX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To normalize array A based on the MAX array, we need to divide each element in A with the corresponding element in MAX. However, since the sizes of A and MAX are different, we need to perform the division in a specific manner.

One way to achieve this is by using the np.repeat() and np.reshape() functions to repeat the MAX array along the second axis (axis=1) of A, and then perform the division. Here is the modified code that should work for your case:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[9, 1, 9, 4, 4, 9],
              [8, 9, 8, 1, 1, 2]])

MAX = np.array([[2, 7, 3],
                [7, 3, 3]])

w = MAX.shape[1]  # window size

MAX_repeated = np.repeat(MAX, w, axis=1)  # repeat MAX w times along axis=1
MAX_reshaped = np.reshape(MAX_repeated, A.shape)  # reshape to match A

out = A / MAX_reshaped / w  # perform division and normalize by window size

print(out)
```

Comment: You'd be better using [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) instead of `np.repeat` and `np.reshape`

Comment: That's true, I hadn't thought of that before, but I think it must indeed be better.

Comment: @braian Thank you. I think it needs a little edit. This line should be: "MAX_repeated = np.repeat(MAX, A.shape[1]/w, axis=1)". I will accept this as true solution.